# Differences between Visual Studio 2010 RC and RTM

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, ide

I have been using the RC version of VS2010 for a while now. I wanted to know if anyone has a summary of what changed between the RC version and RTM?

I just loaded the RTM and noticed some small things different. I searched around but can't find anything around about it.

If there is nothing out there that lists these differences, can we start listing them here as you find them?

Answer (score 3):

"[No Intellisense with VS 2010 RC (and how to fix it)](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/02/26/no-intellisense-with-vs-2010-rc-and-how-to-fix-it.aspx)" is a blog post by Scott Gutherie about a couple of things that are different between RC and RTM.  "[Visual Studio 2010 Released](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WPFAndTextBlurrinessNowWithCompleteClarity.aspx)" by Scott Hanselmann has a reference to a change between RC and RTM as well.

---

To be more specific in each:

First one references a [blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/psteele/archive/2010/02/26/no-intellisense-in-visual-studio-2010-rc1.aspx) noting:

> Why were the default options for
>   Intellisense turned off when I did a
>   fresh install of Visual Studio 2010
>   RC1?

The second one wasn't the right link, so I did change it, here's the key quote:

> A little confusion about this in the
>   comments. Folks feel very strongly
>   about this stuff, understandably. Just
>   like color blindness, some people are
>   sensitive to this stuff and others
>   "can't see it." One person in the
>   blogs didn't like go for
>   "indiscernible" and showed a
>   screenshot. Here's the deal. If you
>   are running VS2010 RC, you don't have
>   this fix. This will be in the RTM.
>   Here's a 100% screenshot, followed by
>   the zoomed in version. The takeaway is
>   this. If you didn't like the rendering
>   before, you will now. This is/was some
>   subtle stuff, but it's indiscernible
>   in the RTM, so be happy! I took the
>   screenshot from a daily build, not the
>   actual RTM, which hasn't happened yet.

These aren't the only changes probably, but these were references to what I could easily find about it so I'm trying to give a useful answer here.

Comment: I dont see much listed in there about it in either article. Can you point me to where they talk about it?